# ofSetColor does not change color when drawing to an ofFbo (using openFrameworks)

Tags: c++, openframeworks

First I'll give an example of code that does what I want it to do. Then I'll give a second example of a small change that causes a problem.

## Working Example

`ofApp.h`:

```
#pragma once

#include "ofMain.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp {
  public:
    void setup();
    void draw();

    ofFbo fbo;
};
```

`ofApp.cc`:

```
#include "ofApp.h"

void ofApp::setup() {
  fbo.allocate(200, 100, GL_RGBA);
}

void ofApp::draw() {
  // Draw a red square to the FBO
  fbo.begin();
  ofClear(255,255,255, 0);
  ofSetColor(255, 0, 0, 255);
  ofDrawRectangle(100, 0, 100, 100);
  fbo.end();

  fbo.draw(0, 0);
}
```

This results in the following red square being drawn to the screen:

[image: working example of red square]

## Broken Example

Now I add two lines to the top of the `draw` method, and I don't get what I expect. Here's the full code of `ofApp.cc`:

```
#include "ofApp.h"

void ofApp::setup() {
  fbo.allocate(200, 100, GL_RGBA);
}

void ofApp::draw() {
  // Draw a blue square directly to screen
  ofSetColor(0, 0, 255, 255);
  ofDrawRectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);

  // Draw a red square to the FBO
  fbo.begin();
  ofClear(255,255,255, 0);
  ofSetColor(255, 0, 0, 255);
  ofDrawRectangle(100, 0, 100, 100);
  fbo.end();

  fbo.draw(0, 0);
}
```

I would expect to get both a blue square (drawn directly to the window) and a red square (drawn to the FBO). But the red square turns black:

[image: broken example with blue and black square]

It seems that calling `ofSetColor` before drawing to the FBO causes everything drawn to the FBO to be black. What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `ofSetColor(255, 255, 255, 255);` or `ofSetColor(255);` or `ofSetColor(ofColor::white);` (all the same) before drawing your fbo.

It is currently drawing with the previous `ofSetColor(...);`.

The same goes for drawing any texture in openFrameworks. For example, if you call

```
ofSetColor(255, 255, 0);
myTexture.draw(0, 0);
```

your texture will be drawn with a yellow tint.

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be a bug.

Maybe you can post this on https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/issues

However, calling `ofSetColor(255, 255, 255, 255);` before `fbo.draw(0, 0);` seems to fix the problem.

I think calling ofSetColor affects the color of the FBO in a weird way. 
For example if you call `ofSetColor(150, 0, 0, 255);` before `fbo.draw(0, 0);` the FBO draws a darker red square.

The more you reduce the r value of the color, it will get darker. That's why calling `ofSetColor(0, 255, 0, 255);` made the square completely black.

Maybe someone can explain better why this happens. But calling `ofSetColor(255, 255, 255, 255);` before `fbo.draw(0, 0);` seems to fix the problem anyway.